# Is this Tcp async/await code considered thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, tcplistener

I wrote some code using TcpListener and async/await which will wait for 3 clients to connect to the server, add them to a list, then do something with the clients:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6015);
    listener.Start();
    var clients = await Task.Run(() => GetTcpClients(listener));

    // Do something with clients

    listener.Stop();
}

private static async Task<List<TcpClient>> GetTcpClients(TcpListener listener)
{
    var clients = new List<TcpClient>();
    var clientsMaxReached = false;

    while (!clientsMaxReached)
    {
        var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        clients.Add(client);
        if (clients.Count == 3)
            clientsMaxReached = true;
    }

    return clients;
}
```

What I am concerned about is whether it's okay to use a List for the clients instead of a thread-safe collection, since the await may resume on a different thread. Also, just wondering if my TcpListener usage is thread safe too.

I don't see a problem since no two threads will ever access the list or TcpListener at the same time, but just thought I'd check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the accesses to list and listener are thread safe.

The `clients` list is not accessed and accessible by anybody else until the list is completely built. Any code after await will not execute until the awaited task/method is completed.

For the `listener` it's pretty much the same but in opposite direction. The instance is passed to `getTcpClients()` method but any other access is blocked until this method stops working with the instance.